# local variable 'driver' referenced before assignment mistake due to failed to install chrome driver

Tags: python

I have dilemma caused by failing to install chrome driver when I tried to install and use tvdatafeed python package

https://pypi.org/project/tvdatafeed/
On this site it writes "Import the packages and initialize with your tradingview username and password. *If running for first time it will prompt chromedriver download, type 'y' and press enter*."

I have a problem with my visual studio code, that it knows where the python interpreter is installed, but it still won't execute in terminal despite workspace file which could run on another computer.

```
{
"folders": [

    {
        "path": "..\\Psample"
    },
    {
],
"settings": {
    "terminal.explorerKind": "external",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"
}
```

}
[image]

So when I first run the script it look like this. I have to install code runner and execute my python file there. However, code runner does not take inputs from its window. So the chromedrive is not downloaded and installed.

And when I run that script again

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tvDatafeed\main.py",
> line 248, in __webdriver_init
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py",
> line 69, in **init**
> super(WebDriver, self).**init**(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
> File
> "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py",
> line 90, in **init**
> self.service.start()   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
> line 74, in start
> self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1360, in
> _execute_child
> args = list2cmdline(args)   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 565, in list2cmdline
> for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):   File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\os.py", line 822, in fsdecode
> filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`. TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "f:\TraidingViewTA\tv1.py",
> line 7, in 
> tv=TvDatafeed(username, password, chromedriver_path=None)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tvDatafeed\main.py",
> line 137, in **init**
> token = self.auth(username, password)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tvDatafeed\main.py",
> line 212, in auth
> driver = self.__login(username, password)   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tvDatafeed\main.py",
> line 152, in __login
> driver = self.__webdriver_init()   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tvDatafeed\main.py",
> line 260, in __webdriver_init
> driver.quit() UnboundLocalError: local variable 'driver' referenced before assignment

Then how do I install the chromedriver manually and set the correct driver value? I downloaded chromedriver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads here manually and it does not work

Answer (score 1):

"Traceback (most recent call last): File "f:\TraidingViewTA\tv1.py", line 7, in tv=TvDatafeed(username, password, chromedriver_path=None) File"

You forgot to set the path to your webdriver.
There is nothing to install, just point path to the chromedriver.exe you downloaded.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for the reply. You mean the environment variable PATH?

Comment: When creating your TvDatafeed object, try setting the path argument where you saved the chromedriver.exe.
chromedriver_path = "wherever your chromedriver.exe is"
tv=TvDatafeed(username, password, chromedriver_path=chromedriver_path )